# Python regex on an EDI document

Tags: python, regex

Good morning, I've a question that is killing me.
I'm try to intercept, with a script, some document that customer send to us.
So I've to generate a xlsx file with some schedule in it.

This is what the document looks like:

```
    E2EDP10001                    300                5     0     02 4M0 035 503 
K  C5M                ANTENNE                               24                         L06S2            CKL           17105098                           16.0                          20170516                                                32.0                                                                          2                    03                                                                                                                     000006                                                  
E2EDP16001                    300                6     5     033D20170609    20170609  24                                                                                                                          
E2EDP16001                    300                7     5     033D20170630    20170630  0                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                8     5     033D20170728    20170728  8                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                9     5     033I20170731    20170806  8                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                10    5     033I20170828    20170903  8                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                11    5     033I20170918    20170924  8                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                12    5     033I20171016    20171022  8                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                13    5     033I20171023    20171029  0                                                                                                                           
E2EDP16001                    300                14    5     033I20171030    20171105  1
```

and this is what I write down:

```
import os
import sys
import re
abs_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

#delfor_folder
delfor_path = abs_path+r"/DELFOR"
delfor_archive_path = delfor_path+"/Archive"
#deljit_folder
deljit_path = abs_path+r"/DELJIT"
deljit_archive_path = deljit_path+"/Archive"
#delins_folder
delins_path = abs_path+r"/DELINS"
delins_archive_path = delins_path+"/Archive"
counter = 0
#ciclo i delfor
for file in os.listdir(delfor_archive_path):
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        continue
    elif file.__contains__(".txt"):
        data = []
        #partner = 'unknown'

        with open(delfor_archive_path+"/"+file) as f_input:
            for row in f_input:
                try:
                    data_row = re.match(r'(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d{8}) +(\d{8})', row)
                    continue
                except:
                    data_row = re.match(r'(\d{3})+I(\d+) +(\d{8}) +(\d+)',row)

                cliente_row = re.match(r'EDKA1003 +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\w+) +(\w+)', row)
                materiale_row = re.match(r'EDP10001 +(\d) +(\d+) +(\w+)', row) #TODO togliere i primi due caratteri dell'ultimo gruppo

                print(cliente_row)

                '''
                if data_row:
                    if data_row.groups()[0]:
                        data.append([partner] + list(data_row.groups()[:-1]))
                    else:
                        partner = data_row.groups()[-1]
                '''
```

so I've some doubt in the try exept and also I need, if it's possible, some advice for make the code work better. 
The work that I need to do is to.
Make a table that contains:

```
E2EDP10001                    300                5     0     **02 4M0 035 503**
```

the code between the <<**>> exept for the 02

```
E2EDP16001                    300                6     5     033D20170609    20170609  24
```

The two date formatted aaaammdd and the first group with the 4 characters (in this case **033D**)

and also the quantity in the end (in this case **24**)

I only need advice in out to proprer search through this.
My code is working if I don't do any statement and/or condition. I mean, if I print out a single re.match per row...

Any advice can be helpful.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not much understood what do you want to do. It looks you have some mix tabular records with different numbers of columns. So I would use `split` function to `row` and get list of columns. You can use regex only to columns or you can just divide string data of column how you will need.

**Here is my code - only part:**

```
data = list()
with open('data.txt') as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        cols = row.split()
        if len(cols) == 8:
            data.append(cols[:4] + ['**' + ' '.join(cols[4:8]) + '**'])
        elif len(cols) == 7:
            data.append(cols)

print str(data).replace('],', '],\n')
```

**The program output:**

```
[['E2EDP10001', '300', '5', '0', '**02 4M0 035 503**'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '6', '5', '033D20170609', '20170609', '24'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '7', '5', '033D20170630', '20170630', '0'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '8', '5', '033D20170728', '20170728', '8'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '9', '5', '033I20170731', '20170806', '8'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '10', '5', '033I20170828', '20170903', '8'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '11', '5', '033I20170918', '20170924', '8'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '12', '5', '033I20171016', '20171022', '8'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '13', '5', '033I20171023', '20171029', '0'],
 ['E2EDP16001', '300', '14', '5', '033I20171030', '20171105', '1']]
```

The `re.match` does not throw Exception if did not match string, only returns none. So, I feel has no sense to use `try ... except` block.

If you ask how to improve your code. I do not like, you use this:

`file.__contains__(".txt")` I would replace by this: `file.endswith(".txt")`

I everytimes try to join paths with `os.path.join(dir1, dir2, ...)`

Other thing is if you need parse a lot of data with regex, there is better to use compiled regular expression.

**For example:**

at the begining of the script you define

```
DATA_ROW_RE = re.compile(r'(\d{3})+I(\d+) +(\d{8}) +(\d+)')
```

later in you script you will just use:

```
data_row = DATA_ROW_RE.match(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW I need something like `[' 4M0 035 503', '033D20170609', '20170609', '24'], [' 4M0 035 503', '033D20170630', '20170630', '0'], [' 4M0 035 503', '033D20170728', '20170728', '8']` and so on...

Comment: I have modify the script implementing your answer and by adding somo line to reach any text variation. And, gladly, it works. So, Thank you!!!!